# Spring boot REST API to mediate between UI and back-end

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I have a JavaEE MVC web app running on Wildfly 10. Now there is an idea to separate back-end and front-end. I want to create a RESTful Web Service with Spring Boot so it will mediate between front-end (Angular) and back-end (JavaEE app). For example the front-end will make AJAX calls to my RESTful Web Service and will handle the response returned in JSON format.

Within my JavaEE app I could make REST calls this way and the appropriate method would be invoked depending on the path. For example:

```
@Path("products")
public class ProductsResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Products> getAllProducts() {
        // return list of products
    }
}
```

But for now I do not understand how can I make the Spring Boot RESTful service get data from my current JavaEE web app? They will be running on different servers.

**UPD**: providing more info on my JavaEE app, it has a DAO layer and EJBs as a service layer. For example:

```
public class ProdBean implements ProdBeanInterface {
@Override
public List<Product> getAllProducts(DataSource ds) {
    ProdDao productDao = new PostgreSqlProdDao(ds);
    return prodDao.getAllProducts();
}
```

The `ProdBeanInterface` is injected into a servlet controller and is further used for DB access fetching data from DAO layer.

Comment: It looks like your backend application is using Jersey and is exposing at least some form of REST API itself. Is that the case? If so, why rewrite it? If not, the details will depend on exactly how the backend application is set up.

Comment: @chrylis My backend app is not exposing any REST API yet. I have only tested it to work as in the example above. For now it is a pure JavaEE MVC app. I came up with the idea to develop a Spring boot REST API out of curiosity and in order to learn new technology.

Comment: Is the code you posted from your backend? Because that *is* a REST API.

Comment: @chrylis I've just updated the post. The first example with REST API is not present in my back-end app now. I have provided it as an example of how it could work if my app had a REST API. I have just tested it but would like to develop a REST web service with Spring Boot.

Comment: Ah, then you'll probably just need to wrap EJB remote calls in controller methods. The Adapter Pattern may be helpful.

Comment: @chrylis Should I change the `ProdBeanInterface` from `@Local` to `@Remote` and then expose it as a remote interface to the Spring Boot Web Service. So that the Spring Boot RESTful service will call it through that remote interface for example, using RMI ? Am I correct or missing something?

Comment: @chrylis seems like an old question but in case any one needs an answer this is what i came up with: If you have to maintain a mediator in between your backend and frontend then you should be exposing your back end as REST services and you should be consuming these services from your mediator layer via HTTP requests (Mediator RestController code should programmatically connect to backend REST and send HTTP request from within code).